# Getting "ORA-28000: the account is locked" while connecting from Python to Oracle

Tags: cx-oracle, python-3.8, oracle11gr2, tnsnames

I have Python (3.8.3) and Oracle DB (11g Release 2 server) installed in my local system. Both of the software are working fine individually. I can run programs in python as well as I have tables created with data in Oracle DB which I am able to access through Oracle SQL Developer & SQL Plus.
But when I am trying to connect Oracle DB from python I am getting error as account locked. I have installed and executed import cx_Oracle successfully. But I am getting error when I am trying to execute below code.

**1. Local initialization method -**
*connection = cx_Oracle.connect("oe/oracle@localhost:1522/orcl11g2")*

**2. Connecting through TNSNAMES.ORA -**
*connection = cx_Oracle.connect("oe", "oracle", "orcl11g2")*

**Error -**

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-28000: the account is locked*

**My TNS Details -**

**File location -** *D:\app\Admin\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\NETWORK\ADMIN*

*ORCL11G2 =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = ORCL11G2)
)
)*

Please help me. Just let me know if you need to know anything more to guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [SQL Developer](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/users_secure.htm#ADMQS218) or SQL*Plus, connect to the DB as a privileged user such as SYSTEM or SYS, e.g:

```
sqlplus system/yourpassword@localhost:1522/orcl11g2
```

Then run the SQL statement:

```
alter user oe account unlock;
```